# How to modify fetch interval of URLs in the crawldb?

Tags: nutch

Suppose I have configured `db.fetch.interval.default` to have value `10`. Furthermore, suppose I have successfully crawled a website (e.g. `http://example.com`). At this point, all the URLs in the crawldb will have a fetch interval of 10 days.

The problem: I want to change the fetch interval for one particular URL, say for `http://example.com/daily-news/`. I want to edit the crawldb to change the fetch interval for `http://example.com/daily-news/` to 2 days instead of 10. How can I edit the crawldb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CrawlDb is a Hadoop map file which is not supposed to be edited. The Nutch "inject" command provides an option `-overwrite` which allows to overwrite existing entries and set a custom fetch interval. The URL file should contain (tab-separated):

```
http://myUrl/ <tab> nutch.fetchInterval=custom_interval_in_sec
```

For more details please check the command-line help shown by `bin/nutch inject`. You can then verify the overwritten record using `bin/nutch readdb <crawldb> <myUrl>`. Please also note that the fetch status of the overwritten record is lost resp. it's set to "injected".

Comment: From my understanding, the difference between using `-overwrite` and `-update` is that using `-overwrite`, the urls injected will be marked as unfetched (and hence will definitely be fetched), whereas using `-update`, the url will only be fetched only if a) it has never been fetched before, or b) it has been fetched before but the new injected fetch interval has passed, making the url eligible for fetching. Correct?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I am using Nutch version 1.15. Is there anything specific to Nutch 1.x I should be aware of?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - also with `-update` it's possible to set the fetch interval. However, the time of the next fetch will stay the same. In your case, you have to wait until the 10 days have passed. Using `-overwrite` will force that the URLs gets refetched immediately in the next cycle.

Comment: Where can I find the documentation about the format of the URL file? (In particular, I'm looking for the documentation that explains the possibility of having per-URL settings and the tab-separated format of the file). I tried to use the documentation search and Google, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You'll find information about all Nutch commands/tools in the [Nutch wiki, here bin/nutch inject](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=122916815). In doubt, just call `bin/nutch inject` to see the up-to-date command-line help (it may also differ for the actual version of Nutch) or look into the source code or the [API docs](https://builds.apache.org/job/nutch-trunk/javadoc/org/apache/nutch/crawl/Injector.html).